# How to edit a file a local file (eg. for a JavaScript editor)?

Tags: javascript, file

I am developing a Javascript code editor and I need it to edit files on your device so it doesnt need to download anything

I saw in chrome://settings/content that there was a permission for that and i want to know how to use it

I have not been able to find a way to use the permission

[Extra clarification here {imgur}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK20y.png)

Comment: Note: The file is “local”, as JS runs on the client’s machine.